# How to swap the first and last elements of a linked list

Tags: c++, list, linked-list

I am trying to swap the first and last elements of a linked list, but I have not been able to find a solution. My logic, or pseudo code, is to:

- set the second-to-last node's `next` to the first node.
- set the first node's `next` to a `nullptr`.
- set the last node's `next` to the first node.

My current code is:

```
void SingleList::swapFirstAndLast()
{
    Node *current = first;

    while (current->getNext()->getNext() != nullptr)
    {
        current = current->getNext();
    }
    // current is equal to the second to last node

    //set last node to first node
    current->getNext()->setNext(first);
    //set first node to nullptr
    first->setNext(nullptr);
    //set second to last to first node
    current->setNext(first);
    // set the first equal to the last node
    first = current->getNext();
}
```

And my current output is:

```
Swap first and last nodes: 
List before :    200 50 300 25 


 --------------------------- 
List after :    200
```

I'm not necessarily looking for a direct code answer, but any tips or advice on what I am missing here would be much appreciated.

Comment: Swapping elements of a linked list shouldn't depend on the elements location in the list.

Comment: Just swap the data in the 2 nodes, not the pointers that maintain the list.

Comment: When you execute `first->setNext(nullptr)` you are losing your only reference to everything after the first element.

Comment: @MarkRansom This question is not about efficiency, but about learning to deal with pointers and moving pointers in a list. I know how to swap data that is trivial.

Comment: @MFisherKDX What would you suggest is a good way to set the new final node to null?

Comment: Try changing this line `//set last node to first node   current->getNext()->setNext(first);` to `current->getNext()->setNext(first->getNext());`

Comment: @RichardCritten> that is assuming a lot. Who is to say the data in the nodes is swappable? And that no external pointers or references to those exist?

Comment: @linuxartisan I see where you are going with that and I believe that is a correct addition to the code but, unfortunately, it does not change the output.

Comment: *"set the last node next to the first node"* -- why? I thought you wanted the middle of the list to come between the formerly-last node and the formerly-first node. (Not to mention that seeing `setNext(first)` occur twice in your code suggests an error. Two different nodes will precede `first`?)

Comment: My advice is to draw some pictures. At the top of a sheet of paper, draw four circles in a row to represent the nodes of a list. Draw arrows between the circles to represent the "next" pointers. Label the nodes. At the bottom of the sheet, do something similar, but draw the list as you want it after the swap. Then draw the middle rows, each like the row above it, but with one arrow changed.

Comment: @Jacob I think you misdirected your comment.  I wasn't talking about swapping data, I was talking about swapping pointers.  The position in the list still shouldn't matter, the code will be the same.

Comment: One tip.  Be aware that "current->getNext()->getNext()" could crash. i.e. if the first getNext() == nullptr, you'll try to dereference that.  Could happen when the list is short.

Comment: @spectras I agree, the question is incomplete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logic has a flaw in its third point.

- set the last node next to the first node

It should be.

- set the old last node as the new first node.

Lets walk through your pseudo code. I assume **first** is a global pointer that points to the first node of your list.

```
|200|50|300|25|
 ^
first
```

after the while run the **current** pointer now points to the node with a value of 300

```
|200|50|300|25|
 ^      ^
 first  current
```

then we change the node with value 25 to point to **first** which leads to this

```
|50|300|25|200|
    ^      ^
   current first
```

after that we close the list at **first** by pointing it to null, And set **first** as next of **current**

```
|50|300|200|
    ^   ^
current first
```

Now the error can be seen the reference to 25 is now lost.
After that we change the global **first** pointer to point to the next node of **current** which should be the node with value 25 but is not since it was replaced with the original **first** node.

To fix this you should change the end of your function like this.

```
Node * oldLast = current->getNext();
//set second to last to first node
current->setNext(first);
// set the first equal to the last node
first = oldLast;
```

Comment: @JaMiT adapted the answer based on your input.